# How to make select label always appear at top in MUI?

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui

I want to create a material ui selector that label always appear at top. I added placeholder to select component. Here is what I want to do.

[image]

When not focusing to select component or at the beginning, it looks like this.Label overlaps the place holder.

[image]

What I want to create select label always seem at the top and not overlaps the placeholder.

Here is the code at codesandbox

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/multipleselectplaceholder-material-demo-forked-s0zww?file=/demo.js)

```js
import * as React from "react";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select from "@mui/material/Select";
import InputLabel from "@mui/material/InputLabel";

const names = ["Oliver Hansen", "Van Henry", "April Tucker", "Ralph Hubbard"];

export default function MultipleSelectPlaceholder() {
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState(null);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setPersonName(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: 300, mt: 3 }}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          label="Age"
          displayEmpty
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          renderValue={(selected) => {
            if (selected === null) {
              return <em>Please Choose Name</em>;
            }

            return selected;
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem value={null}>
            <em>Clear</em>
          </MenuItem>
          {names.map((name) => (
            <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
              {name}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 22):

https://codesandbox.io/s/multipleselectplaceholder-material-demo-forked-t06gm?file=/demo.js

Just add to Select:

```
notched={true} // Makes space between lines
```

and to InputLabel:

```
shrink={true} // Keeps label at top
```

Comment: I'm curious, is there a way to place the label above the box rather than intersecting it?

Comment: I don't know if there is other solution, but i would do it like this: (removed notched and label from Select and moved InputLabel with sx)

https://codesandbox.io/s/multipleselectplaceholder-material-demo-forked-7zyv2?file=/demo.js

Comment: thanks for this answer..I was literally looking for something like this

Comment: Thaanks bro! work for me

Answer (score 2):

If you're wrapping TextField yourself, it's

```
   InputLabelProps={{
    shrink
  }}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, you can simply pass **shrink** prop to the `InputLabel` component