# React - MUI dropdown with display value other than selected

Tags: reactjs, select, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I try to achieve a dropdown that displays multiple buttons for selection and a display value independent of the drop-down items like so:

[image]

In this example, the user can select different scales for a chart that displays two metrics. In case both metrics have different scales, the drop-down shows "mixed" in case they both have the same scale it shall show either "linear" or "log", depending on the overall scale.

I tried with `MUI Select component` and added a custom function to change the display value, but I get the warning:

```
MUI: You have provided an out-of-range value `linear` for the select component.
```

Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.

Here my code snippets:

```
const displayMetricScale = () => {
    return (scale_metric1===scale_metric2) ? (scale_metric1) : "mixed";
};

<Select
    label="Scale"
    value={displayMetricScale()}
    defaultValue="mixed"
    renderValue={(p) => p}
>
    <MenuItem>
    <FormControl>
        <FormLabel>Metric 1</FormLabel>
        <Button onClick={changeScaleLin} >
            Linear
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={changeScaleLog} >
            Logarithmic
        </Button>
    </FormControl>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem>
    <FormControl>
        <FormLabel>Metric 2</FormLabel>
        <Button onClick={changeScaleLin} >
            Linear
        </Button>
        <Button onClick={changeScaleLog} >
            Logarithmic
        </Button>
    </FormControl>
    </MenuItem>
</Select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things I would like to suggest here:

**First:**

Add a `value` prop to each menuItem. This way they can be "matched" by the Select component as valid selections. Like so:

```
<MenuItem value="linear">
  ... 
</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value="log">
  ...
</MenuItem>
```

This should hopefully get rid of the warning you have mentioned in your question.

**Second:**

The second problem you need to solve is to have "mixed" be a valid selection item.

A solution could be to show "mixed" when there is no selection. This solution isn't ideal and not scalable to any more than 1 custom item, but might work for you. The comments in the code should explain better what I am trying to put forth:

```
const displayMetricScale = () => {
  // Return empty when you want to show "mixed"
  return (scale_metric1===scale_metric2) ? (scale_metric1) : "";
};

<Select
  label="Scale"
  value={displayMetricScale()}
  displayEmpty=true // To be able to show a value when value is empty
  renderValue={(p) => p === "" ? "mixed" : p} // If p is empty, show "mixed"
>
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested this code so it may have problems but I have a hunch it will work

Comment: Thanks Hassan. I tried your solution. Unfortunately ```renderValue={(p) => p === "" ? "mixed" : p}``` doesn't do anything, I don't know why. But at least "linear" and "log" does not produce warnings anymore and for "mixed" I created an empty MenuItem that I disabled: ```<MenuItem value="mixed" disabled sx={{height:'0px'}}>```. Unfortunately the height is not 0px, height doesn't affect the Item and its visible with a small offset.

Comment: Did you make sure to add the `displayEmpty=true` prop to the select?

Comment: You are right. I forgot about that. Now it works! It suppresses the warning and shows "mixed". The only issue that is left now is that I have an ```InputLabel``` which is labeling the select and it overlays the Input of "mixed" with the Label name "Scale" as the value is empty for "mixed" cases.

Comment: Great, I fixed that last issue with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70261803/how-to-make-select-label-always-appear-at-top-in-mui